# A query regarding rewriting an infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

Given an infinite alternating series $S_0 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{F(n)^{p}}$ that is 'convergent' (but not necessarily 'absolutely convergent'. (where $F(n)$ is some appropriate function over $n$; $p$ is a real number).

Moreover, $S_0=0$ and some unknown $x$ appears in each $F(n)$.

Can we take all the (alternative) negative terms in $S_0$ to the R.H.S. (transforming the original series to the form $S_a = S_b$) without changing the solution space of this new series w.r.t. the original series?

(I would like to argue that since we can rewrite the partial sums of $S_a$ and $S_b$ in the form $\sum_{n=1}^ka_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^kb_n$, convergence of the two series is unnecessary as at every stage we are adding the same number of terms of each series.)

Edit: Corrected with a better example.

Comment: How can be $S_0 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{K^{p}}$ convergent?

Comment: Apologies. The example is incorrect. I will have to rethink a better example to rewrite it. But, the essence of the question is can 'some' alternating series $S_0$ that is convergent but not absolutely convergent be rewritten without changing the solution space?

Comment: What du you mean by "solution space"? Some rearrangements of terms is allowed without changing the sum of the series, if that is what you mean. (For example, it's ok to permute a finite number of terms.)

Comment: Assume series includes a variable $x$ in every term. For some values of $x$ the equation $S_0 = 0$ is satisfied. Can we take all negative terms to the R.H.S. (i.e. infinite number of terms), and rewrite it as $S_a = S_b$ such that the solution space (in terms of $x$) for original and rearranged series is same?

Comment: If it's conditionally convergent, then you're breaking it up into a divergent positive series and a divergent negative series, so neither sum exists unless I'm wildly wrong somewhere.

Comment: You'd have to prove before going any further that both the resulting series were convergent. The easiest way to do that would most likely be to prove that the original series was absolutely convergent.

Comment: What I think is even if the two series are divergent we can have them such that both are equal. A simple example will be $S_a = 1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5....$ and $S_b = 2/4+3/9+4/16...$. Now, both are divergent. But, they are also equal. So, convergence would not be a necessary condition. ??

Comment: Try $F(n)=n$ and $p=1$ in your example and look up "alternating harmonic series".

Comment: @TheoryQuest1The terms are equal, but when do we stop adding them up? An infinite sum represents the limit of the adding process, not the *result* of the adding process since there's always another term to add.

Comment: 'but when do we stop adding them up?' - we don't. But, we can argue that for any first 't' terms, the sum of terms of both sub-series is equal, thus, the series are equal as the rate of divergence in both is always equal..  what is wrong with this above argument ?

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 I think the short answer is that it redefines the notation. Could you put some of these issues into the question? Then hopefully someone can write a full answer to them all. It's hard in comments and also frowned on.

Comment: I agree. But can I request you to update it in a more formal notation. I am sure I was able to get the point across but I will struggle to write it up formally (I don't have mathematics background, more of an interest).

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 I've edited the question---it'll appear once approved. Feel free to then edit my edit!

Comment: thank you. its approved.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that what you're trying to do is define an infinite sequence of *equations*

$$\sum_{n=1}^ka_n=\sum_{n=1}^kb_n$$

and say that the limiting case as $k\rightarrow\infty$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

is defined even if the two series are divergent.

The problem is that the notation doesn't actually work that way. The counting variables $n$ in the two sums are taken to be independent of each other. They're not really the same variable—it's just convenient to give them the same name.

So the "limiting equation" **isnt** equivalent to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-b_n)=0$$

because it discards the pairing between  $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Another way to think of it is to imagine that we use $n$ to count through the first  sum, then reset it to $1$ to start counting the second sum.

Comment: Thank you again. But I am not convinced of the underlying objection as. Lets consider 'Proof by Induction'. It has 3 steps: (1) Prove a Base Case. (2) Assuming its true for the case $k=v_0$ steps (3) using this 1. and 2. prove the truth for $k=v_0+1$. Thus, we have proved it values of $k$ (including $k\rightarrow\infty$). Now, for a given alternating sequence, I am struggling to see why we can't do the same..

Comment: I think the issue is simply that the notation doesn't quite express following that process, because of the pairing issue. Maybe somebody can put it more clearly.

Comment: Not an issue. Thanks for the patience/help.

Comment: It's just that the final equation isn't specific enough to unambiguously express your process, and we can't start saying things like $\infty=\infty$ to say each side has the same number of terms. Anyway I'm hoping somebody else will have a go at explaining why.